# How to create a google cloud pubsub pull subscriptions with service account by terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

In the terraform documentation for *google_pubsub_subscription*, it mentions having a *oidc_token* property under *push_configuration* allows push-subscriptions to utilise service account, but has no mention on how to use service account for **pull subscriptions**.

How can explicitly set the service account to be used during the creation of **pull** pubsub subscriptions?

I tried adding *oidc_token* block, but it did not worked as it does not expect that block directly.

Scenario:

1. I have a service account that has access to pubsub topics (and necessary permissions to attach subscriptions to it) in **Project_A**
2. I want to create subscriptions to those topics in **Project_B** in terraform.
3. I need to explicitly use this service account in terraform, so i can create subscriptions at *Project_B* to topics of *Project_A*

*google_cloudfunctions_function* resource for example, has field called service_account_email for setting service account. But there is no for *google_pubsub_subscription* resource, **for pull subscriptions** in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_subscription).

Answer (score 4):

Actually the service account (`service_account_email`)is to be specified inside the `oidc_token` section (you had to go further in the doc :)

below a working example of a push sub with service account and audience (optional)

```
variable "project" {
  type = string
  default = "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "example" {
  project = var.project
  name = "example-topic"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "example" {
  project = var.project
  name  = "example-push-subscription-with-auth"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.example.name

  push_config {
    push_endpoint = "https://example.com/push"
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = "${var.project}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
      audience = "https://example.com/push"
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: yes but it is for push_config, which is for push subscriptions right? this will be a *pull* subscription which does not accept oidc_token alone.

Comment: pull suscriptions creation don’t use identities like service accounts. It’s the responsibility of your subscriber, pulling the messages from the subscription to hold an identity with a proper authorization to be able to pull the messages. In the case of push subscription, optionally you provide a service account to be able to push and interact with the endpoint if it requires authentication.

Comment: I created a service account to access pubsub topics from another project, and now with using that service account i want to create subscriptions in my project. With that goal in my mind, (topics from another project, i can access with service account, need to create pull subscriptions on my project) i need to use service account in terraform, right?

Comment: OK so you are talking about the service account you're using with terraform to create a new pull subscription in your project but attached to an already existing topic in another project. If I understood well you need to flow these steps : 
1. give `pubsub.subscriptions.create` permission or the `roles/pubsub.editor` role to the terraform service account on the subscription project.
2. give `pubsub.topics.attachSubscription`permission or `roles/pubsub.subscriber` role to the terraform service account on the requested topic

Comment: For more details about the needed permissions/roles you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#required_permissions))

For more details on how to use a service account with terraform you can check this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials)

Comment: thanks for all those info! What i try to achieve is: utilising a different service account in pubsub subscription creation in terraform (not the default one that terraform uses) to create subscription to topic in another project. This service account  will be used for creating subscriptions, and has access to the topics - and necessary permissions- of the other project. For example, in google_cloudfunctions_function resource, i can set  service account with using service_account_email. But there is no such parameter in google_pubsub_subscription resource for pull subscription.

Comment: You cannot choose a service account for a Pull Subscription. If the subscription is attached successfully to your topic it will get the messages published to your topic. It's up to your subscriber to choose the right identity to be able to pull message from the subscription. Finally  you can't compare Cloud Function and the Pull subscription: Cloud Function is a computing / processing platform, so it makes sens to be able to set a service account for it. A pull subscription is a mere data buffer with "no processing to be customised". Hope this helps.

Comment: can i attach a subscription to a topic (from other project) if i don't have a IAM role? If not, i am trying ti create & attach a subscription to a topic with using the service account that has necessary IAM role, but how can i set it in terraform? this is what i asked.

Comment: I detailed the different steps in a new answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @ayyayyekokojambo does it help the new answer ?

Answer (score 1):

***I'm adding another answer, because the question has changes a lot after the different comments.***

Here is the solution **with the hypothesis that a topic `topic-sof` is already created in a different project than the subscription one.**

1. I created a service account (SA) on the subscription project, I called it `stackoverflow-playground-sa` and gave it only the `Pub/Sub Editor` role as you can see in the screenshot below.
   [image]
2. I gave the SA the the `Pub/Sub Subscriber` role on the topic `topic-sof` s show in the screenshot below.
   If you don't do this step: you will get this error at terraform apply

```
 Error: Error creating Subscription: googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action
```

[image]

**Of course I did the 2 first steps of roles assignments with a user with enough permissions on both projects**

3. I created a json key file for my SA and downloaded under `/path/to/my/key/stackoverflow-playground-sa.json`
4. I authenticated as my SA using

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/my/key/stackoverflow-playground-sa.json
```

**So it can be used by terraform to create the subscription.**

5. Here is the terraform configuration to create the subscription

```
variable "subscription_project" {
  type = string
  default = "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_PROJECT>"
}

variable "topic_project" {
  type = string
  default = "<YOUR_TOPIC_PROJECT>"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "pull-subscription-of-topic-in-another-project" {
  project = var.subscription_project
  name  = "pull-subscription-of-topic-in-another-project"
  topic = "projects/${var.topic_project}/topics/topic-sof"
}
```

6. Run (`apply`) my terraform and the subscription `pull-subscription-of-topic-in-another-project` is created and attached to the topic `topic-sof` in the other project.
7. I published a message to `topic-sof` using the web ui.
8. Still authenticated as `stackoverflow-playground-sa` thanks to step 4, I pull the message (using gcloud in my treminal) et voilà message received:
   [image]

**To summarise** : there is no service account to specify in your terraform configuration for this requirement. The service account and its key is set outside terraform (step 1 to 4) so that terraform process can be authenticated and authorised to create the resources configured (the subscription in our case).
**Besides using a service account key as in step 4 is a bad practice, security wise. An alternative is to use**

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

That will let you set the default credentials of the user of your choice. Given that user has the roles I set for the SA.